# Angular service return observable from callback function

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular-services

I'm using **Angular 8**.

In my service, I'm using a library which accepts callback function and gives value in the callback function.

My service method is

```
raw(qrInfo, res?): Observable<string> {

  return manager.getData(res.width, (res1) => {
    return of<string>(res1);
  });
}
```

I want to subscribe to this `raw()` method and get the result of `res1` in the controller

```
constructor(
  private myS: MyService
) {}

data() {
  this.myS.raw(info, op).subscribe(res => {
    console.log(res);                              // Get value here
  }
}
```

But this is not working. **How can I return observable from callback function?**

Comment: i think it should be enough when you do: return manager.getData(res.width); This shuold return the observable to subscribe... There is not need to return on observable again with of()

Comment: Then the manager method starts giving error as callback not defined. The manager method is not returning promise or observable and need callback method to call it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a new Observable inside your raw() method by following this  [documentation](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/create.html) to emit the callback result into your Observable.

```
raw(qrInfo, res?): Observable<string> {
  /** Returns the freshly created Observable **/
  return Observable.create(function(observer) {
    /** Call your method with the callback **/
    manager.getData(res.width, (res1) => {
      /** Emit the callback response to the Observable **/
      observer.next(of<string>res1)
      /** Complete the Observable to close it **/
      observer.complete();
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: He's already creating an observable inside the raw method by using `of`

Comment: I think it's implied that `manager.getData` is a callback method without a return value (or at least it's not an Observable) so you have to create it using `Observable.create`.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `Subject` inside the MyService and then subscribe to it from your component.

```
managerData$ = new Subject<any>();

raw(qrInfo, res?): Observable<string> {

  manager.getData(res.width, (res1) => {
    this.managerData$.next(res1);
  });
}
```

And then in component:

```
constructor(
  private myS: MyService
) {
    this.myS.managerData$.subscribe((res) => { ... } );
  }

data() {
  this.myS.raw(info, op);
}
```

**NOTE**: If you need to unsubscribe from it, you can do it like this:

```
private managerDataSubscription: Subscription;

constructor(
  private myS: MyService
) {
    this.managerDataSubscription = this.myS.managerData$.subscribe((res) => { ... } );
  }
```

And then you can call `this.managerDataSubscription.unsubscribe();` where ever you need (in `ngOnDestroy` for example)